# Force.com IDE Successful Deployment but No Change in Salesforce

Tags: apex, force.com, class, ide

I was able to successfully deploy a change via FORCE.COM + Eclipse. I wanted to delete an APEX class by updating the Status from "Active" to "Deleted". Force.com IDE told me the deployment was successful in production. However when i check Salesforce the Apex class is still there and active.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you denote the class as deleted in the sandbox? By actually deleting it?

Comment: I updated the status in the xml document from "Activ" to "Deleted".

Comment: If there are dependencies on that class the destructive change will fail but will record a success. Make sure there are no dependencies first.

Comment: there are some cusotm objects that are referenced by the apex class so if I set those custom objects to In development would that work?

Comment: @JYern Check your deployment status of setup in production. Did you see a request-Id at that particular time when you saved to server? If not, right click -> Force.com-> Save to server again on the xml file where you are changing status.

Comment: When I choose the Save to server option the Apex Class status changes back to "Active" from "Deleted"

Comment: You should be *deleting* the resource, not setting it's status to deleted. See [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm), which has a note about the "deleted" status: "The class is marked for deletion. This is useful for managed packages, because it allows a class to be deleted when a managed package is updated." It doesn't actually *delete* the resource. You need to actually use the Delete option in the Eclipse IDE to force a delete.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry I'm new to this, so how would I delete the resource in Force.com IDE?

Comment: in eclipse, delete the class (Right Mouse Button | Delete)  -- or, in the Force.com UI, delete the class and then refresh Eclipse

Comment: @sfdcfox I believe that setting `Status` equal to `Deleted` in the metadata and then deploying up is [a pretty standard way of using Eclipse to delete files in production](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006188).

Comment: @adrianlarson i did not know this - thanks

Comment: @AdrianLarson It may be documented that way, but I've never had it work that way. I've always had to physically delete it which triggers an appropriate delete call. It's simply unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

@j Yern, please check if there are any references in that class. Even though you might be seeing success it might not be doing exactly what it should be doing.

Comment: Thanks, yes there are dependencies to other custom & standard objects/fields.  Do i have to pull that out of the APEX class? Or is there a way to just delete the class by bypassing the validation for references?

Comment: @JYern - see sfdcfox comment - that is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, how would I delete the resource rather than setting the class to Deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

@j Yern, if you have code references then simplest way to do is first comment out everything in that class and save it and then try deleting it.
Example :

`// Custom controller for wrapper example
public with sharing class WrapperExampleController 
{
   /*
         YOUR LOGIC HERE
   */
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have used the strategy outlined by the [Success Community](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006188) (as in your OP, I believe), and I experienced the same reported success when the delete did not take place if I had other `Apex` or `Visualforce` referencing what I was trying to delete. **The solution is to remove all references to the deleted resource.**

For example, when trying to delete:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectServices { ... }
```

I realized I had not yet deleted:

```
@IsTest class MyObjectServicesTests { ... }
```

Or:

```
trigger MyObject on MyObject (before insert)
{
    MyObjectService.someAction(trigger.new);
}
```

Etc.